# android crash on SIGSEGV /SEGV_MAPERR

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

there is an issue that makes the app crash. the message of the crash is

```
SIGSEGV /SEGV_MAPERR at
OS: Android: 0.0.0 Linux 4.9.148 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 23 14:50:38 CST 2021 aarch64
CPU: arm64
GPU: -
0  libart.so            (Missing)
1  libart.so            (Missing)
```

the crash will happen in seconds after the app launched. I did some research and someone said that issue is maybe with Gson when it tries to save data into the SharedPreferences. I think this is not irrelevant because after clearing app data everything is ok until the crash happens again after some hours. so is there an idea to fix and the real reason for the crash? thanks

Comment: Does it show some stack trace of the crash in the error report?

Comment: the only log available is                                                                                                              S: Android: 0.0.0 Linux 4.9.148 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 23 14:50:38 CST 2021 aarch64
CPU: arm64
GPU: -
0  libart.so            (Missing)

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1978

Comment: Please update the post with the Android version you are using.

Comment: @kiner_shah sure.  there are some devices that this crash happen on them but for my self testing it was huawei mate 9 android 9 version